# Allow Users adjust Text Size in Browser

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-compatibility, view

How do I enable users the ability to increase the font size on SharePoint sites, by using the settings in their browser.

For example in using IE, users can use View > Text Size > Larger etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fonts aren't increasing in size, then you'll need to redefine the CSS for your site to use `em` as units for font size, rather than explicit pixel/point font sizes.

Here's a post about the different font size units in use today:

http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/